# Eclipse Facelet HTML Validator: Cannot apply expression operators to method bindings

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf-2, facelets, el

The Eclipse Facelet HTML Validator reports an error "Cannot apply expression operators to method bindings" for the following line:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{!empty managedBean.getSomething('ENUM_VALUE', someInt)}">
```

I found this in the [Juno help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/tasks/jsf_elvalidation_prefs.html) (I'm using Kepler):

```
Applying operator to method binding
#{bean.action * 5}
If bean.action indicates a method "action()" on bean, then it is not legal EL to treat its result as a value. In the example, multiplying action by 5 attempts treat it is as a value.
```

I'm having trouble understanding why it's not legal to treat its result as a value? What's the correct way to write the EL then? Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28605864/1725096

Comment: The link above, in which BalusC says "EL validation in Eclipse is quite an epic fail. It seems like it's using regular expressions to validate EL syntax instead of a true stack based parser like as EL itself is doing."

Answer (score 25):

If you like you can hide the error message by setting

<kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Web</kbd> -> <kbd>JavaServer Faces Tool</kbd> -> <kbd>Validation -> General Problems</kbd>

the value `Applying method operator to binding` to `Ignore`.

Comment: Well, this is a fine mitigation for the Eclipse issue, but it does not show "the correct way to write the EL".

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried putting paranthesis around your method.
Like this:

```xml
#{!empty (managedBean.getSomething('ENUM_VALUE', someInt))}
```

This way JSF evaluates the method and then checks for null or empty.

I am no expert in JSF, but I had the same problem in one of the similar expression:

```xml
#{some_method() == 0 and some_other_method() eq 'some value'}
```

I saw the same issue shown by Eclipse but the page was running correctly. After I put paranthesis around both of my expressions, Eclipse did not show that error.

Comment: I am learning here and would like to know the reason for downvote please. Thanks.

Comment: I rechecked my answer. I recreated the situation. Eclipse does not show error when your method expression is under parantheseis. Please tell me why you downvoted my answer ?

Comment: This worked! thanks. Idk why you were downvoted originally.

Comment: This is still present in Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). But the code compile and run perfectly.