# Eclipse gives too many false errors and warnings on EL expressions in JSF files

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf, el

I have run into a weird situation. I have an application which was originally developed in RAD and uses a construct like

```
rendered="#{bean.show and user.can('foo')}"
```

Our developers use mix of RAD and Eclipse Juno / Kepler.  So we need to make the code work in both the environments.

In RAD, the above line does not generate any errors.  When I export the project as archive and import it into Eclipse Juno, it generates this error

> Cannot apply expression operators to method bindings

Our environment is Websphere 8.5, RAD / Eclipse, JSF 2.1

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, if you face a false EL validation error in a JSF file in Eclipse, try peeking around in *Window > Preferences > Web > JavaServer Faces Tools > Validation* and tune some settings currently (unnecessarily) set at *Error*.

[image]

Your particular problem is triggered by "Applying operator to method binding" which indeed defaults to *Error*. If upgrading Eclipse to most recent version is somehow not an option, setting it back to *Warning* should tone down it.

After all, EL validation in Eclipse is quite an epic fail. It seems like it's using regular expressions to validate EL syntax instead of a true stack based parser like as EL itself is doing. There are several entries below "Type Coercion Problems" and "Type Assignment Problems" which are unnecessarily set to *Error* and known to cause false errors.

#### See also:

- [Method must have signature "String method() ...[etc]..." but has signature "void method()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083469/method-must-have-signature-string-method-etc-but-has-signature-void/)
- [Eclipse errors on #{component.valid}: "valid cannot be resolved as a member of component”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941072/eclipse-errors-on-component-valid-valid-cannot-be-resolved-as-a-member-of-c/)

Comment: Thanks BalisC.  I will check the validation settings.  But I am still confused as to why the error goes away when I either a) Use $ instead of # or b) Change the order.  Would you be abel to explain tha tpart to me?

Comment: This error popped up on me my projects with a fresh install of Eclipse Mars.1. So Eclipse seems to have changed it's default here to ERROR again.

Comment: I opened https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540785 for this. I still reproduce with Eclipse 2018-09.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error with any of these statements:
`<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!bean.isValid(obj)}">
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not bean.isValid(obj)}">`

I resolved the error by changing the statement as follows:
`<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.isValid(obj) == false}">`

I found yet another example that resolved the problem:
`<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.isValid(obj) eq 'false'}">`