# Eclipse errors on #{component.valid}: "valid cannot be resolved as a member of component”

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf, el

I've the below piece of code in a JSF page:

```
<p:inputText ...
    styleClass="labelledInput-input #{component.valid?'':'validation-failed'}"/>
```

Eclipse produces an error on `component.valid` part as below:

> valid cannot be resolved as a member of component

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Eclipse versions older than Mars. Eclipse isn't smart enough to determine that `#{component}` in this particular case actually references `UIInput` subclass and incorrectly thinks all time that it's `UIComponent` superclass, which indeed doesn't have a `isValid()` property. You can basically just ignore'n'run it. It's a false error and everything should work just fine.

If you want to get rid of the false error and can't upgrade to Mars, then go to *Window > Preferences > Web > JavaServer Faces Tools > Validation*, unfold *Type Coercion Problems* and set *Unary operation boolean coercion problems* to *Ignore*.

[image]

<sup>Screenshot borrowed from [this blog](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2014/10/jsf-22-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-wildfly.html) in all courtesy.</sup>

While you're at it, also do the same for *Unary operation number coercion problems*. This should prevent same errors on same kind of EL operations on number based properties not defined in the abstract superclass.